# MacOS Safari and Chrome have WebGL display issue

Tags: macos, plugins, safari, webgl, display

Have a look at the attached image

[image: 1]

- the Safari browser with macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.

Also there is a video 
https://share.vidyard.com/watch/AZyZGJJ4tJvAQDCYiUQD6W with a closed issue. It is this plugin http://3dflipbook.net . Generally the plugin works well. This problem was not met on other OS: Windows, Android or iOS. Does anyone has any ideas what is wrong?

Best regards,
Ivan.

[1]:

Comment: Looks like failure to clear the buffer. Are you calling `context.clear()`?

Comment: i did not, THREEJS does not require this and why then it works on some of macs well and only in couple it fails?

Comment: Assuming failure to clear is the actual problem, I think the WebGL standard simply doesn't specify the initial state of a canvas. So it might initially be clear and it might not be. Browsers are correct if they do it either way. All still a complete guess though.

Comment: Found this stream https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/865 - it seems like MACs have some problems with WebGL.

Comment: @Tommy, you're right - `renderer.clear()` doesn't seem to actually clear the rendering context in Safari on macOS High Sierra.

Comment: @IvanBerezanskiy, this is the relevant issue: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/12598

Looks like it's tight to the graphic card driver (reproducible with "Intel Iris Graphics").

Comment: As mentioned by Ken Russell on that GitHub issue, a driver fix is included in the upcoming High Sierra `v10.13.2` release and could be already tested in the `v10.13.2 beta4` (https://developer.apple.com/news/releases/?id=11162017a).

Comment: Well. It is a good news. I hope Apple users like to update their devices).

Answer (score 1):

I'm also experiencing this bug, only happens in safari on high sierra.  Have you logged an issue with WebKit?  I was about to do the same thing.

Comment: No i have not logged.

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm that WebGL in Chrome is broken in Mac OSX High Sierra. I'm on a 2011 MacBook Pro.

Same machine, Firefox Quantum can play WebGL however

Testing using https://get.webgl.org

Most odd

Answer (score 0):

This bug happens because we disabled anti aliasing for the webgl context.  If you turn it back on the issue goes away.  Probably not the answer you want if like us you're doing it in the shaders instead.  The guys from webkit have already fixed the issue their end and its fixed in the latest technical preview of safari so just waiting for it to get to the release build

Comment: Do you mean we need: renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true});?

Comment: Can't speak for three.js but in normal webgl antialias:true should be the default.  We're finding here that the latest High Sierra fixed the issue in safari for us so you might not have to now.

Answer (score 0):

One of my customers confirmed, using antialiasing resolves the issue. So create render in this way:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true});
```

Comment: also want to mention that i had this exact code but was using a 'let' and still wasn't getting results in safari, but i change 'let renderer' to 'var renderer' and it fixed everything